# locate function usage on dataframe without using UDF Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am curious as to why this will not work in Spark Scala on a dataframe:

```
df.withColumn("answer", locate(df("search_string"), col("hit_songs"), pos=1))
```

It works with a UDF, but not as per above. Col vs. String aspects.  Seems awkward and lacking aspect. I.e. how to convert a column to a string for passing to locate that needs String.

`df("search_string")` allows a String to be generated is my understanding.

But error gotten is:

```
command-679436134936072:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String
df.withColumn("answer", locate(df("search_string"), col("hit_songs"), pos=1))
```

Comment: what is the error are you getting ?

Comment: I am getting error `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable` with pyspark also. atleats with spark 3

Comment: That's a question for elsewhere. But this is about scala

Comment: sorry. not able to understand your question. I thought you said it's working in python.  The underneath API is always same. so it could not be possible that it works in python but no in scala. And I just tested it. It's not working in Python. Reason being, API expects String not column. both are different data types.

Comment: Get that but i see another example that does work as I thought.

Comment: you can either write UDF or use map for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244439/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-gaurang-shah).

Comment: Udf i did but point is why cannot we convert to string and use locate.

Comment: that's how the API is designed. it takes one dimesion object (string) not multi dimension object like column (which has multiple rows). so no you can't change it.

Comment: From an example elsewhere i thought locate(df("search_string") would make a string as opposed to col.

Comment: no, it's string column

Comment: I am going to look at that example again but formulate your answer i suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Understanding what's going wrong

I'm not sure which version of Spark you're on, but the `locate` method has the following function signature on [both Spark 3.3.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#locate(substr:String,str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pos:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (the current latest version) and [Spark 2.4.5](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) (the version running on my local running Spark shell).

This function signature is the following:

```
def locate(substr: String, str: Column, pos: Int): Column
```

So `substr` can't be a `Column`, it needs to be a `String`. In your case, you were using `df("search_string")`. This actually calls the `apply` [method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#apply(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) with the following function signature:

```
def apply(colName: String): Column
```

So it makes sense that you're having a problem since the `locate` function needs a `String`.

### Trying to fix your issue

If I correctly understood, you want to be able to locate a substring from one column inside of a string in another column without UDFs. You can use a `map` on a `Dataset` to do that. Something like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

case class MyTest (A:String, B: String)

val df = Seq(
  MyTest("with", "potatoes with meat"),
  MyTest("with", "pasta with cream"),
  MyTest("food", "tasty food"),
  MyTest("notInThere", "don't forget some nice drinks")
).toDF("A", "B").as[MyTest]

val output = df.map{
  case MyTest(a,b) => (a, b, b indexOf a)
}
output.show(false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
+----------+-----------------------------+---+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|_1        |_2                           |_3 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
+----------+-----------------------------+---+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|with      |potatoes with meat           |9  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|with      |pasta with cream             |6  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|food      |tasty food                   |6  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|notInThere|don't forget some nice drinks|-1 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
+----------+-----------------------------+---+
```

Once you're inside of a `map` operation of a strongly typed `Dataset`, you have the Scala language at your disposal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Confirms for me.